# post values using ajax but js don't get the updated values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I ran simple ajax too post values in the same page which I saves into session variables, which works fine but whenever i print those session variables in console it don't shows the latest values.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    function showValues() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:  $( "form" ).serialize(),

        success: function(data){
          var x = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['q10']); ?>;
          console.log(x);
        }
      });
    }
    $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
    $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
    showValues(); 
  });
</script>
```

Above script serialize the values from radio, checkbox and select inputs later i saved those on the following variables

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['q10']))
{
  if($_POST['q10'] == 2){
    $_SESSION['q10']=1;
  }else{
    $_SESSION['q10']=0;
  }
}
```

Initially I set $_SESSION['q10'] = 0 and console shows this value but whenever i changed the value it shows the previous value. It didn't update

P.s I get the changed values after refreshing the page. shouldn't i get the updated values in the console

```
<nav class="segmented l3_seg">
     <input type="radio" name="q10" value="1" id="10a">
     <label for="10a">Richtig</label>
     <input type="radio" name="q10" value="2" id="10b">
     <label for="10b">Falsch</label>
   </nav>
```

Comment: Javascript is run by the browser (client) and php is run on the remote server so you cannot just run php code from js.

Answer (score 0):

Many comments and article you will found regarding php is running in server side and Javascript is running in client side. PHP run one time and rendered data to browser one time if you want to reconnect with server/php again you need to use ajax that you are doing.

**In short** , you need to use js variable which containing ajax returned response.

Return response from php

```
if(isset($_POST['q10']))
{
   ....
   return $_SESSION['q10'];
}
```

And display in console as

```
success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

Read about ajax `dataType`